# How to create a drop down menu of users from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

How to create a drop down menu list of users of the database?

I want to make a drop down list of all the users of my database to the the html with in a drop down menu, I don't how to query it and connect it to my database.

EDIT

The users I want to populate in the drop down menu are the user that can access the mysql database, not a single database with a record of user.

Comment: We don't have enough info to give you specific instructions. You have better luck looking for a general tutorial on how to connect to and query from a database. Once you have some code we can help you make it work.

Comment: The users I want to populate in the drop down menu are the user that can access the mysql database, not a single database with a record of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to mysql database from php you can use mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") ";
}
```

to get the users and create dropdown menu you can use this code (assumed that you have table users with id and username fields):

```
echo "<select>";
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username FROM users");
if ($res) {
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['username'] . '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: How to show the users in  database in html? Instead of the users of a single database, I want to show a list of all users that can access the databases.

Comment: @user5789297 You can try to use this query `select user from mysql.user;` when using login as root.

Comment: as for the database connection, what should I fill it in with?

Comment: You can pick any database that exists.

Comment: never mind i think i got it.. thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get all users details for  this code

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','raxesh');

    $get_all_users=mysqli_query($con,'select * from login');

    echo '<select name="allusers">';

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get_all_users)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['uname']."</option>";
    }

    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated you should use mysqli or PDO.